# libgdx - sprite does not rotate

Tags: rotation, libgdx, sprite

This is the create() Method:

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spaceships/tfighter0.png"));
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
sprite.rotate(180f);
```

And the render() Method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.begin();
batch.draw(sprite ,200,200);
batch.end();
```

Shouldn't the sprite be rotated now? It just looks the same as the png no matter what degree I put into the rotate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
sprite.draw(batch)
```

Instead of

```
batch.draw(sprite,x,y)
```

works